# Gradle Error - Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':project:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I updated Android Studio and started getting this error. I have no experience with gradle and as such can't seem to figure out what could be going wrong.

Here's the full error.

> Gradle: Execution failed for task ':project:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':project:mergeDebugResources'

Comment: I'm getting the same error... If you add "--stacktrace" to the gradle command I get the following stack trace

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.createManager(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/android/utils/ILogger;)Lcom/android/sdklib/SdkManager;
 at com.android.builder.DefaultSdkParser.initParser(DefaultSdkParser.java:76)
....

Comment: I'm seeing this too with Studio 0.2.10 and build tools 18.0.1. Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Use the last version of the gradle plugin (current is 0.6.3)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So after reading up on gradle, I tried this command 'gradlew compileDebug --stacktrace' so as to see a more detailed error. It turns out the problem was actually a duplicate resource issue  and gradle was just giving me a generic error.

Comment: I didn't know about 'gradlew compileDebug --stacktrace'. This is hereby marked a life safer for me.

Comment: How do you run the gradlew command? I am using Android studio on a Mac.

Comment: Go to View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal. You can now run your gradle commands from there.

Comment: You can go to view Gradle and double click on compile debug

Comment: It says "command not found". Can you help me with that ? I'm using Android studio on Mac

Comment: You can try to run this command to change the rights : chmod +x gradlew

Comment: gradlew is a bash script, so try: 'bash gradlew compileDebug --stacktrace' on a Mac.

Comment: on Windows , in  Android Studio's terminal its gonna be  `.\gradlew compileDebug --stacktrace`

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue after changing Gradle & Gradle Plugin version from File->Project Structure->Project->, And after changing it back to previous version all errors are gone and working perfectly again.

Answer (score 0):

My problem with this issue was that I had an ampersand (&) in my directory name.