# Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':mergeDebugAssets'

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Been trying to debug this issue for ages. To be honest, I'm not too familiar with Android Studio so I would appreciate some help. When I go to build the app I get the following:

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':mergeDebugAssets'
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'newrelic'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:2.397.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'newrelic'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:2.397'
}
```

And here is the output of `./gradlew --stacktrace assembleDebug`

```
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':mergeDebugAssets'

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugAssets'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:283)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:214)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:276)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:78)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':mergeDebugAssets'
    at org.gradle.util.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:527)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:510)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.hash(Lcom/google/common/io/InputSupplier;Lcom/google/common/hash/HashFunction;)Lcom/google/common/hash/HashCode;
    at com.android.builder.internal.incremental.FileEntity.getSha1(FileEntity.java:187)
    at com.android.builder.internal.incremental.FileEntity.computeAndReturnSha1(FileEntity.java:171)
    at com.android.builder.internal.incremental.FileEntity.isDifferentThan(FileEntity.java:155)
    at com.android.builder.internal.incremental.FileManager.processFile(FileManager.java:210)
    at com.android.builder.internal.incremental.FileManager.processFile(FileManager.java:225)
    at com.android.builder.internal.incremental.FileManager.processFile(FileManager.java:225)
    at com.android.builder.internal.incremental.FileManager.addFile(FileManager.java:161)
    at com.android.builder.internal.incremental.ChangeManager.addOutput(ChangeManager.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.internal.incremental.ChangeManager$addOutput.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.groovy:88)
    at org.gradle.util.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:62)
    ... 59 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.304 secs
```

Comment: Try the answer from here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009619/gradle-error-could-not-call-incrementaltask-taskaction-on-task-projectmer

Comment: I understand this is a very old question, but I was recently facing the same issue and finally solved it by updating the `build.grade` file with an entry of Kotlin Gradle Plugin. I hope this helps solve the problem if

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds like a bad installation of the Android Gradle plugin. Make sure you're on the latest version, 0.6.3 or later (0.6.2 had problems and we had to quickly spin a new version) and it should be okay. If you're still having trouble, I'd try erasing your Gradle cache directory (`.gradle/caches` in your home directory, usually) and trying again.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, the Gradle Version had been updated too far ahead of the Gradle Plugin Version. This happened automatically as part of an update to Android Studio.

The fix was to open File > Project Structure...

Then downgrade the Gradle Version via the drop down to the last one that was known to work. My config of Gradle plugin version 7.2.1 and Gradle version of 7.4.2 resolved the issue.

Running Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1

Comment: after several attempts, these versions were the ones that worked for me

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it was a compatibility issue.
After upgrading Android Studio, it required me to use a newer version of Gradle.
I upgraded to AGP 8.1.1 and Gradle to 8.1.1 for Android Studio Giraffe

(A bit overkill but did the trick)

Comment: it requires java 17, should switch back to 7.x.x

Answer (score 4):

According to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6f0i3XTtYI you should change gradle version to 7.3.3.

Answer (score 3):

As [Josh Wong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2744216/josh-wang) said, the answer is here: [Gradle Error - Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':project:mergeDebugResources'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009619/gradle-error-could-not-call-incrementaltask-taskaction-on-task-projectmer).

The answer by [Dimeji Isola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992510/dimeji-isola):

> So after reading up on gradle, I tried this command 'gradlew compileDebug --stacktrace' so as to see a more detailed error. It turns out the problem was actually a duplicate resource issue and gradle was just giving me a generic error.